# insert null value using doctrine fixtures (symfony)

Tags: mysql, symfony1, doctrine, fixtures

my question is very simple. I have this model where i want to insert a record with a null value in one of the fields (`finRango`), using the data fixtures of doctrine orm. here's what ive tried:

```
  fila41_zona5:
    MetodoEnvio: dhl
    zona: 5
    inicioRango: 20.00
    finRango: NULL
    precio: 7.15
```

also tried:

```
  fila41_zona5:
    MetodoEnvio: dhl
    zona: 5
    inicioRango: 20.00
    finRango: 
    precio: 7.15
```

and even:

```
  fila41_zona5:
    MetodoEnvio: dhl
    zona: 5
    inicioRango: 20.00
    precio: 7.15
```

I keep always getting a zero (0.00) in the `finRango` field. I defined my schema from the database schema, and this field is not defined with `NOT NULL`. It is part of the primary key of the table, but it can be `NULL` (I need it to be null in a particular case, because of what the model represents). Here's the schema definition generated by the task `php symfony doctrine:build-schema`:

```
//An extract from my config/doctrine/schema.yml:
PrecioEnvio:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: PrecioEnvio
  columns:
    idmetodo:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: true
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    zona:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    iniciorango:
      type: 'decimal(10, 2)'
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    finrango:
      type: 'decimal(10, 2)'
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    precio:
      type: 'decimal(10, 2)'
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    MetodoEnvio:
      local: idmetodo
      foreign: id
      type: one
```

This is the SQL definition of the table, from which this schema was generated:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sawpruebaTienda`.`PrecioEnvio` (
  `idMetodo` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `zona` INT(3) NOT NULL ,
  `inicioRango` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Marca el inicio del rango de peso para el cual este precio aplica.' ,
  `finRango` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL COMMENT 'Marca el fin del rango de peso para el cual este precio aplica.' ,
  `precio` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idMetodo`, `inicioRango`, `finRango`, `zona`) ,
  INDEX `fk_PrecioEnvio_MetodoEnvio` (`idMetodo` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_PrecioEnvio_MetodoEnvio`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idMetodo` )
    REFERENCES `sawpruebaTienda`.`MetodoEnvio` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

Even being uncapitalized in the schema, the fields `inicioRango` and `finRango` are interpreted properly. The only problem is when i try to store the `NULL` value on `finRango`.

I'm using MySQL!

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this working:

```
fila41_zona5:
    MetodoEnvio: dhl
    zona: 5
    inicioRango: 20.00
    finRango: ~
    precio: 7.15
```

Comment: Didn't work either. I tryed `"NULL"` also, not mentioned in the question, but got the same behavior. Also tried specifying `notnull: true` in the schema file for the `finRango` field, rebuilding the model, and loading the fixtures and didn't work... any other ideas? thanks! =)

Answer (score 0):

What if you set default to NULL ?

```
  default: null
  notnull: false
```

Comment: Hi! I don't work on this project since long ago, and I can't test your answer right now... If you tested it yourself, and you are certain that it works, I have no problem with accepting your answer. Please let me know.